# Google Map Info window selection displays data in table

Tags: ms-access, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic

I have a Google map application that displays soil cores taken at various locations.   Some Locations may have more than one core take at the location.  So instead of having multiple icons on the location, I counted the number of cores and display that in the Google Maps info window.
Now I want to click on something in that window that will trigger data to be displayed all the individual cores in a table below the Google Map.     I want to maintain the  zoom level of the map and the info window that is open.

Currently I have a link in the info box that recalls the page with the lat and long of the marker and the database is queried and then displays the information.  but I lose the zoom and the info window.

So I think I want to do something to do with AJAX that will only update the table below.  And I assume something other than a link in the Info Window. And still know the lat and long to do the query. But I am not sure how to word that to look for an example.

Other caveats are its an MS Access database and I am writing in Classic ASP at the moment.

Comment: What does your code look like?  There shouldn't be any issue putting a button or a link in an infowindow that displays information queried from your database in a div outside of the map.  What have you tried?

Comment: Also, if you start developing a new application: do it right. no access, no asp-classic.

Comment: No we are not starting a new app.   We had the database and page before.  We are just trying to make it work better.